# Making TextInput on_text_validate event accessible from another widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a custom widget as a module. My custom widget includes a TextInput and some other stuff inside a FloatLayout widget.

When i import my custom widget i want to use on_text_validate event for TextInput within the Floatlayout.

As you know we can add the button behavior to any widget via ButtonBehavior class but i couldn't find a way to add on_text_validate event to my custom widget.

That's my module named mymodule.py inside my project folder.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
#from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior

Builder.load_string("""

<SearchBar>:
    id: search_bar
    size_hint: 1,.1
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size     

    TextInput:
        id: input
        hint_text: 'search'
        size_hint: .82,None
        height: dp(33)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.565,'center_y': .5}
        multiline: False
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
        padding_x: 20,150
""")

class SearchBar(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

I call it from main.py as

`#:import SearchBar mymodule.SearchBar`

And that's my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
#:import SearchBar mymodule.SearchBar

<MyTest>: 
    SearchBar:
        id: search
        size_hint: 1,.1

#       on_text_validate: root.do_something()

""")
class MyTest(FloatLayout):

    def do_something(self,*args):
        print('done')

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyTest()
Test().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create an event with the same name and shoot it with the TextInput event:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<SearchBar>:
    id: search_bar
    size_hint: 1,.1
    pos_hint: {'top':1}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size     

    TextInput:
        id: input
        hint_text: 'search'
        size_hint: .82,None
        height: dp(33)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.565,'center_y': .5}
        multiline: False
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
        padding_x: 20,150
        on_text_validate: root.dispatch('on_text_validate', *args)
""")

class SearchBar(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SearchBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_text_validate')

    def on_text_validate(self, *args):
        pass
```